# How do you check if a DateTime is Midsummer eve- or day in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

How do you check if a DateTime is Midsummer eve- or day in C#? I'm working on a solution in C# for creating schedulings. It has to check if a DateTime is Midsummer eve- or day in Sweden. Do I have to hard code it in a table? Do I have to implement my own function for this? What is the formula in that case?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be to your advantage to define what Midsummer eve/day is in your question. I've never heard of it in my region, so I'd have to go look it up, which I won't. Is it always the same date every year? Is the date determined some other way (e.g. the 2nd full moon of summer)?

Comment: This library seems to include Swedish holidays, including Midsummer eve and day.  Perhaps it could meet your needs?  https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It has to check if a DateTime is Midsummer eve- or day in Sweden

[In Sweden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midsummer#Sweden) the Midsummer's day is a Saturday between June 20 and June 26:

```
public static bool IsSwedishMidsummerDay(DateTime dt)
{
    return dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday 
        && dt.Month == 6 && dt.Day >= 20 && dt.Day <= 26);
}
```

[Here](https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/sweden/midsummer-day#obs) you find a list of midsummer-dates which show that the rule applies.

Comment: God I feel stupid now. I missed the part when I read about it that it is specifically a Saturday and not any day of the week. Now it's easy :). Thanks.